# how can I check if the HTTP_REFERER contains a string, but not exact match?

Tags: php

I know HTTP_REFERER is not safe as a security measure, but I still want to know.

How can I check if the value of HTTP_REFERER contains www.someexample.com even though it may be www.someexample.com/awards/user/145??

Answer (score 8):

```
if (false !== stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "www.someexample.com")){
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Made that case-insensitive to make it a little more reliable.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER = www.someotherexample.com?param=www.someexample.com =)

Comment: @Fivell: so preg_match is necessary for this case. But I don't think this will happen

Comment: parse_url is buildin function for that

Answer (score 3):

```
if( stripos($_server['HTTP_REFERER'], 'someexample.com') !== FALSE ) {
     // The link is from someexample.com (might not have "www" in it)
}
```

**Note:** This'll also match `http://www.andsomeexample.com`. If you want to prevent that, use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
if( parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])['host'] == 'someexample.com'){
    // You're good to go...
}
```

Comment: Fails if (for some reason) the string is at the start of the referer field - stripos'll return 0 and this'll evaluate to false.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER  = www.someotherexample.com?param=www.someexample.com

=)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Apache, simply perform a [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']