# how to write if (self == top) js code as a php code php equivalent or alternative

Tags: php

actuly i need if my site page run in a iframe then display a code if not in iframe the display another code. i need to do it with php. did you think its possible ?

i need the js condition in my php. how way write it ?
its for iframe. go top or iframe Break
any one help me 
js is

```
if (top != self){
   document.writeln("Hi");
}
else
{
   document.writeln("Bye");
}
```

how to write it in Php

or these way

```
<?php
if ( $i == 1) {?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top != self){
   document.writeln(" <?php $i = 1; ?> ");
}
else
{
   document.writeln(" <?php $i = 2; ?> ");
}
</script>
<?php
if ($i == 1)
{
echo "hi";
}
else 
{
echo "bye";
}   
}
else {
echo "else hi";
}
?>
```

if its possible like these way help me pleas

Comment: What does this do exactly and what is your problem in expressing the same thing in PHP?

Comment: Is `top` a variable and `self` a constant?? Do you want to know syntax or algorithm?

Comment: @Srihari: He's comparing the global `window.top` and `window.self` references in javascript. Since the server has no access to them, it's impossible.

Comment: The second code snippet you've added won't work because all the PHP is executed *before* sending the page to the browser, and all the JS is executed *after*. Please let us know what you are actually trying to achieve, and we may be able to suggest a different approach to the problem.

Comment: actuly i need if my site page run in a iframe then display a code if not in iframe the display another code. i need to do it with php. did you think its possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing top to self is checking if your HTML code is executed in a frame or not. Frames are client side techinique which PHP has no knowledge about, so you cannot express that in PHP.

Only thing you can do for frames is check for http_referer, but that's not the same thing at all. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353180/how-can-i-check-if-the-http-referer-contains-a-string-but-not-exact-match) shows how that is done. Using that, you would check if referer matches your site or not. However, then you have other issues as that is not very reliable, and could end up blocking going through regular links as well.

Comment: pleas see it http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/214953-if-self-top-php-equivalent-or-alternative/ and help me i don't know php... tell me with is work ..!

Comment: @user2642814 those examples deal with server side include files, which isn't the same thing as checking for frames in top != self snippet. Is that what you want? Please rewrite the question so it would be more clear what you really want.

Comment: pleas see my Question i will edit it. see and tell me is it possible ?

Comment: @user2642814 Checking for iframes cannot be realiably done with PHP. You can only check for http_referer but that's very unreliable.

Comment: Ha eis Thanks for help .... hop i wll find something

Comment: @user2642814 I modified my answer and added a link if you want to explore http_referer way of doing it.

Comment: actuly i need if my site page run in a iframe then display a code if not in iframe the display another code. i need to do it with php. did you think its possible ? and again thanks.

Comment: Well, it cannot be reliably done. You can hack something with http referer check but it will only work in some use cases and some browsers.

Comment: You could accept the answer, if you feel this has answered your question.